# No networking connectivity in KVM guests / VPS

Tags: networking, centos, kvm-virtualization, bridge, guest

I'm setting up KVM host on my Centos 6 Dedicated server. I've managed to get the VPS / guests built and running, but they have no connectivity. The IP's have been raised on the guests, they're using my bridge on the KVM (br0) but the IP's aren't being pinged and they can't ping externally. The KVM and the guest are able to ping each other, but the guests can't connect outside the KVM. 100% packet loss. The KVM is able to make and receive external connections.

The command being used to create the guest is:

```
virt-install --name=vps2 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vps2.img,size=8 --ram=512 --os-type=linux --network bridge:br0 --nographics --extra-args='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' --location '/tmp/CentOS-6.9-x86_64-minimal.iso' --boot cdrom
```

Here's my networking settings for the KVM host:

**/etc/sysconfig.network**

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=****
NOZEROCONF=yes
GATEWAY="91.***.***.254"
```

**virsh net-list**

```
Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
--------------------------------------------------
default              active     yes           yes
```

**ifconfig**

```
ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:***:***:7C
          inet addr:91.***.***.216  Bcast:91.***.***.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d267:***:***:47c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2342975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18077 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:112401012 (107.1 MiB)  TX bytes:3782581 (3.6 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:***:***:7C
          inet6 addr: fe80::d267:***:***:47c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:214922 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6170 errors:7 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:7
          collisions:28 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:14366872 (13.7 MiB)  TX bytes:1286723 (1.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:672 (672.0 b)  TX bytes:672 (672.0 b)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:***:***:5E
          inet addr:192.***.***.1  Bcast:192.***.***.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:***:***:E7
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:***:***:96e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:137374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:6725 (6.5 KiB)  TX bytes:8448525 (8.0 MiB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:***:***:66
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:***:***:6666/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:786 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2103722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:33539 (32.7 KiB)  TX bytes:129504050 (123.5 MiB)

vnet2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:***:***:66
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:***:***:6666/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35627 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:1852760 (1.7 MiB)
```

**eth0**

```
DEVICE="eth0"
HOSTNAME=****
HWADDR="D0:***:***:7C"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="19***:***d3"
BRIDGE=br0
```

**br0**

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO="static"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
DNS2="8.8.4.4"
GATEWAY="91.***.***.254"
HWADDR="D0:***:***:7C"
IPADDR="91.***.***.216"
NETMASK="255.255.254.0"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

**route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.***.***.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
91.***.***.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 br0
0.0.0.0         91.***.***.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
```

**brctl show**

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.d067e5e7047c       no              eth0
                                                        vnet0
                                                        vnet1
virbr0          8000.52540098305e       yes             virbr0-nic
                                                        vnet2
```

**The VPS / guest**

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:***.***:E7
          inet addr:91.***.***.217  Bcast:91.***.***.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::***.***:96e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:160593 (156.8 KiB)  TX bytes:1440 (1.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:11 Base address:0x4000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

**ip addr show**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:***.***:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 91.***.***.217/23 brd 91.***.***.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::***.***:96e7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I've tried adding the IP's via the default.xml in the host:

**/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/default.xml**

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>e0***:***45</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0' />
  <mac address='52:***:***:5E'/>
  <ip address='192.***.***.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.***.***.2' end='192.***.***.254' />
      <host mac='52:***:***:e7' name='vps1' ip='91.***.***.217' />
      <host mac='52:***:***:bc' name='vps2' ip='91.***.***.219' />
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I've created various rules within IP tables to allow traffic between the 2 servers, but no luck. I've disabled SElinux and iptables, but still no connectivity.

The IP appears to be raised on my guest, it's using the bridge, it's using Googles nameservers, yet there's no connectivity and I'm unable to ping the guest IP's. My though that was the KVM wasn't allowing bridged traffic between the guests and the outside world, but even with IP tables disabled, there's still nothing.

Do you believe it may be related to a failure between the bridge and the guest? If you need any further info, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I had to replace the 'Broadcast' line with 'Gateway' in my eth0 config inside the guest, now there's external connectivity.

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=52:**:A0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=B***9
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=91.***.***.217
GATEWAY=91.***.***.254
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
```